# Мутирующая таблица

Tags: oracle, база-данных, sql

У меня есть таблица, которая изменяется после вставки/удаления строки. То есть мутация заключается в том, что при вставке в таблицу, надо пересчитать значения, находящиеся в других строках. Я написал триггер, но он не работает, происходит ошибка. Проблема, как я понимаю, возникает, когда в триггере уровня строки есть попытка обратиться к таблице, которая изменяется тем же предложением. В чем причины этой ошибки? И как можно её избежать? И каким образом можно реализовать пересчет значений таблицы при изменении одной строки (instert/delete)?

Comment: Покажите ваш триггер

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, у Вас есть подобные данные:

id field1 field2 field3

1  data1  data2  30

2  data3  data4  50

Вы делаете insert в таблицу, например:

id field1 field2 field3

1  data1  data2  30

2  data3  data4  50

3  data5  data6  70

Из-за вставки вам нужно сделать update, например, всех field3:

30, 50, 70

Проблема заключается в том, что действия вы выполняете на залоченой таблице (не знаю как oracle, я пишу про mysql, думаю, что в oracle тоже самое), т.е.  данные не могут быть обновлены, удалены или как-то изменены, пока таблица залочена.
В mysql это LOCK TABLE/UNLOCK TABLE. По скольку insert по факту еще не завершился, таблицу нельзя обновить, для этого можно пойти другим путем - сделать 2 запроса, 1-й добавит, 2-й обновит. Возможно, что в oracle можно проверить доступность на обновление таблицы, и, например, во второй поток сунуть обновление, либо ждать пока таблица не "освободится", тем самым став доступной для обновления.
Надеюсь, что хоть чем-то помог.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, Вам необходимо обрабатывать вставленные строки в statement триггере after insert. Как вариант, запоминать вставленные строки можно в массиве специально созданного package

```
 TYPE array_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEXED BY BINARY_INTEGER; 
 array array_type;
```

Comment: http://www.oracloid.ru/index.php?t=207

Answer (score 1):

**Ту Алекс Силаев**. Для того чтобы прочитать данные нет необходимости блокировать данные. Оракл не MySQL. Также чтение не требует освобождения таблицы, на это есть реализованная многоверсионность с использованием сегментов отката.

Обычно, ошибка мутирующей таблицы решается двумя способами:

1. Триггер в автономной транзации, но корефеи Оракла не рекомендуют его использовать.
2. И более верный способ. Отложенная обработка в триггере AFTER, как и предложил (14 Мар 14:09) andivanov. Сохраняете данные в массив, потом выбираете их.

Answer (score 0):

Хотелось бы взглянуть на код вашего триггера.

Набросал небольшой примерчик, думаю он направит вас.

```
create table TMP_TEST_TABLE (col1 number,  col2 number, colsum number);

create or replace trigger TR_TBL_TEST before insert or update
    on TMP_TEST_TABLE
    for each row
    begin
        :new.colsum := :new.col1 + :new.col2;
end TR_TBL_TEST;

insert all
       into tmp_test_table(col1, col2) values (1, 2)
       into tmp_test_table(col1, col2) values (3, 4)
       into tmp_test_table(col1, col2) values (5, 6)
select * from dual;
```

---

```
SQL> select * from tmp_test_table;

      COL1       COL2     COLSUM
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          3
         3          4          7
         5          6         11
```